# What is wrong with my serialization mechanism?

Tags: java

This is the code which works fine on Mac OS (JDK 1.6):

```
String s1 = "test";
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
String s2 = (String)(new ObjectInputStream(in).readObject());
```

On linux CentOS 5.4 Java says:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3F3F0005
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:783)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:280)
at com.XXX.SerializableTest.testWorks(SerializableTest.java:26)
[...]
```

What is it about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ObjectInputStream` only works on data written by `ObjectOutputStream`.

The `getBytes()` method of `String` isn't a Java Serialization mechanism; it merely encodes the character string using the default character encoding for your platform.

---

Using the no-argument `getBytes()` method is a bad idea for most applications. As I stated, it uses the default encoding for the platform it runs on. If the result will ever be used on a different machine, it is likely to break.

For most applications, you should explicitly specify the character encoding to be used.

It's important to keep in mind that some byte sequences are invalid in some character encodings. If you want to convert an arbitrary sequence of bytes to a character string, pick an encoding that assigns a single character to each byte value (if there is such a thing; the common ones I'm familiar with don't use every byte).

I'm guessing that, instead of `"test"`, the string in question was created something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buf = ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(buf);
oos.writeObject(x);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
/* BAD! you should specify encoding! */
String encoded = new String(buf.toByteArray());
```

Instead, the last line should look like this, where `encoding` is a suitable character encoding, as discussed above:

```
String encoded = new String(buf.toByteArray(), encoding);
```

However, far better technique would be to use an encoding that was specifically designed for representing "binary" data as text. [Base-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base-64) is widely supported. [Base-85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_85) is more compact, but not as widespread. You'll need a third-party library to perform use one of these encodings. (Base-64 is implemented in the Sun [Oracle] run-time, but it's not part of the public API.)

Comment: Why it works on Mac OS and doesn't work in Linux? I want to validate that data were properly serialized by some other instrument beforehand. Thus, the only thing I have is an instance of `String` which came from some other place. At this snippet I have to de-serialize a stream of `char`-s into an object.. How can I do this?

Comment: @Vincenzo - I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Are you creating your own serialization technique? Then don't use `ObjectInputStream`; it's a specific format just like you couldn't use a JPG decoder to read a new image file format that you invented yourself.

Comment: @Vincenzo - Okay, reading your comments on the other answer, I think I might understand. Is the string `s1` really `"test"`? Or is it some unreadable gibberish? If the latter, please see the update to my answer.